# Why is this Python program raising an error while updating a dictionary?

Tags: python, file

The problem given is that I have been given a file with some text. I have to count the number of times all the word occurs.

What I have tried so far:

```
def print_words(filename):
    input_file = open(filename, 'r')
    words = input_file.read().split()
    result = {}
    for word in words:
        if word in result:
            result.update({word:1})
        else:
            result[word] += 1
    for count in result:
        print(count + ' => ' + str(result[count]))
```

The error I am getting:

```
File "wordcount.py", line 50, in print_words
    result[word] += 1
KeyError: 'We'
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Because you have the `if word in result` and `else` the wrong way around

Comment: Seriously, why the negative vote? I followed each and every guideline... :(

Comment: @jonrsharpe: that's an answer.

Comment: @user3243703: I didn't downvote, but your question title is entirely unhelpful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I think as nneonneo does. This should be in answer and if you post it, I will select yours because you were the first to answer.

Comment: @nneonneo Is it all right now?

Comment: Don't let the downvote get you down.  I believe some folks are downvoting just because they think the question is too easy, forgetting that they themselves were beginners once.

Comment: @user3243703 there you go, happy to help

Comment: @jonrsharpe Accepting in four minutes. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you iterate through your words:

```
for word in words:
    if word in result:
        result.update({word:1})
    else:
        result[word] += 1
```

You add `word` to `result` using `update` *only when it is already there* (`if word in result:`). If it is not there, you try to add one to its value anyway, which Python can't do, hence the `KeyError`.

The minimal fix is either:

1. Switch the lines inside the `if` and `else` blocks around; or
2. Change to `if word not in result`.

Alternatively, you can simplify with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)

for word in words:
    result[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you are saying that if the item is already in the dictionary, set it to 1. But if it doesn't exist, you try to reassign the value. This is obviously the wrong way round.

---

To fix this, replace:

```
if word in result:
```

with:

```
if word not in result:
```

There you go, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, what's happening is that the variable `word` contains the "We".  You're trying to increment the counter in the dictionary, but Python is telling you that "We" is not (yet) a key in the dictionary.

This indicates that there's an error in your add-to-dictionary logic and, indeed, looking at the program you only add the word to the dictionary if it's *already* in the dictionary.  Replace

```
 if word in result:
```

with

```
 if word not in result:
```

and you'll be on your way.